# Bootstrap navbar does not work properly on Chrome for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying the bootstrap 3 navbar in my meteor app but it does not work properly on mobile. The problem is that the toggle does not appears. 
It works as expected in Firefox only. After installing the bootstrap package in my app, I just copied the code for the navbar from the [bootstrap web site.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) Do you know what could be happening? I have not done any change in the code.

Thanks in advance.

[image] [image][image][image]

Comment: have you included both css and js? look here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you forgot add following line into your < head >:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more about it at http://getbootstrap.com/css/ (Mobile first)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I'm new with this of web development. It worked well in Chrome